# Python UnicodeDecodeErro no jupyter notebook. Trabalhando com .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode

Estou aprendendo a fazer manipulações com arquivos `.csv` no Python com o *jupyter notebook*.

Extraí um arquivo do sistema, em `csv`, separado por vírgulas, mas quando fui abrir recebi esse erro:

```
arqsb2 = open('arquivos/sb2.csv','r')

sb2 = arqsb2.read()


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-084f7ffc9ea2> in <module>()
----> 1 sb2 = arqsb2.read()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1022110: character maps to <undefined>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Rafael, no método de abertura do arquivo, tenta passar o encoding já, algo como: `arqsb2 = open('arquivos/sb2.csv',encoding='utf-8','r')`, pesquei isso da [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Answer (score 0):

Rafael você pode abrir o documento da seguinte maneira:

```
open('arquivos/sb2.csv',encoding='utf-8','r')
```

Caso continue dando esse erro olhe qual o encoding do seu documento.
Outra forma muito interessante de trabalhar com csv, alias a melhor lib de todas e utilizar o pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('caminho/do/documento.csv')
```

O pandas e extremamente poderoso para se lidar com documentos do tipo csv e você terá uma ferramenta completa de definitiva.

Comment: não funcionou -> File "<ipython-input-1-d5e9fe0d14a7>", line 1
    y = open('arquivos/estoque.csv', encoding='utf-8', 'r')
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: y = open('arquivos/estoque.csv', encoding='utf-8', 'r')

Comment: File "<ipython-input-1-d5e9fe0d14a7>", line 1
    y = open('arquivos/estoque.csv', encoding='utf-8', 'r')
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Isso é um erro muito comum. A função leva dois tipos de argumentos o  de chave e valor e o posicional. No caso os argumentos posicionais vem antes. Então tenta.                                        Y= open ('arquivos/estoque.csv','r', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: y = open("estoque.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cd696e05bb90> in <module>()
----> 1 print(y.read())

~\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 28: invalid continuation byte